# Mule unzip transformer for processing zip file contents

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I need to unzip a zip file, so I am looking for unzip transformer similar to gzip-uncompress-transformer.

```
<sub-flow name="unzip" doc:name="unzip">
    <gzip-uncompress-transformer></gzip-uncompress-transformer>
    <logger level="INFO" message="Unzipped payload" doc:name="Logger" />
    <byte-array-to-string-transformer
        doc:name="Byte Array to String" />
    <logger message="Payload is #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
</sub-flow>
```

Does mule provide such kind of transformer out of the box, or do I need to write custom transformer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not believe Mule has a zip transformer due to the number of files that can result from using it. Such as decompressing a single zip could result in X files (one input file results in many output files). Whereas a gzip transformer is always 1 to 1 (one input file results in one output file).

Comment: Thanks Chad. I ended up writing my own tranformer